# Apply LOOCV in java splitting with a specific condition

Tags: java, weka, loocv

I have a csv file containing 24231 rows. I would like to apply LOOCV based on the project name instead of the observations of the whole dataset.
So if my dataset contains information for 15 projects, I would like to have the training set based on 14 projects and the test set based on the other project.

I was relying on weka's API, is there anything that automates this process?

Comment: Are you planning on writing Java code or Python?

Comment: @fracpete Java code

Answer (score 0):

For non-numeric attributes, Weka allows you to retrieve the unique values via `Attribute.numValues()` (how many are there) and `Attribute.value(int)` (the -th value).

```java
package weka;

import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils;

public class LOOByValue {

  /**
   * 1st arg: ARFF file to load
   * 2nd arg: 0-based index in ARFF to use for class
   * 3rd arg: 0-based index in ARFF to use for LOO
   *
   * @param args    the command-line arguments
   * @throws Exception  if loading/processing of data fails
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // load data
    Instances full = ConverterUtils.DataSource.read(args[0]);
    full.setClassIndex(Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    int looCol = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    Attribute looAtt = full.attribute(looCol);
    if (looAtt.isNumeric())
      throw new IllegalStateException("Attribute cannot be numeric!");
    // iterate unique values to create train/test splits
    for (int i = 0; i < looAtt.numValues(); i++) {
      String value = looAtt.value(i);
      System.out.println("\n" + (i+1) + "/" + full.attribute(looCol).numValues() + ": " + value);
      Instances train = new Instances(full, full.numInstances());
      Instances test = new Instances(full, full.numInstances());
      for (int n = 0; n < full.numInstances(); n++) {
        Instance inst = full.instance(n);
        if (inst.stringValue(looCol).equals(value))
          test.add((Instance) inst.copy());
        else
          train.add((Instance) inst.copy());
      }
      train.compactify();
      test.compactify();
      // TODO do something with the data
      System.out.println("train size: " + train.numInstances());
      System.out.println("test size: " + test.numInstances());
    }
  }
}
```

With [Weka's anneal UCI dataset](https://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/datasets/datasets-UCI/) and the `surface-quality` for leave-one-out, you can generate something like this:

```
1/5: ?
train size: 654
test size: 244

2/5: D
train size: 843
test size: 55

3/5: E
train size: 588
test size: 310

4/5: F
train size: 838
test size: 60

5/5: G
train size: 669
test size: 229
```